# See links download progress in Mail

Tags: mail.app, links

I received an email in Mail (OS X 10.8.5), with a couple of links to Dropbox files. I CTRL-click on them and choose the option "Download linked file", and the download starts… but there's no progress indicator anywhere (unlike with Safari downloads). How can I check whether the download has finished or not, or even if it's progressing?

Comment: Try the Activity monitor in mail- Window.

Comment: The Activity Monitor shows nothing. Otherwise I wouldn't have bothered to ask.

Comment: I can not read your mind! So to spare me time or get me motivated to answer your question, disclose what have you done so far without success. I am talking about the Activity in Mail app, and it does show exactly what is happening. alt+cmd+0

Comment: I said in my question "no progress indicator anywhere". Don't you think that any reasonably experienced Mac user already knows about the Activity monitor, and therefore, already includes it implicitly when saying "anywhere"? Anyway, that's just a misunderstanding: the point is that I did try it again before responding, by sending an email to myself with a link, and the Activity monitor shows nothing.

Comment: Buscar is not asking about the Activity Monitor app as he says "Activity Window in Mail app, " which is a different thing

Comment: He said "Activity monitor" in his first response, so I used the same name when responding. Anyway, we both are referring to the same window, the one that shows activity when downloading mails or syncing IMAP folders (just so that you see that I know the window you're talking about… :-) )